# How to self host asp.net web api over the internet?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, owin

This question has been asked multiple times here and still i can't get my head around a few things about this since i'm a bigger beginner then most people here with programming in general. So this is my scenario to make you understand where i'm at, i apologize for the amount of text. I have created a .NET web api and uploaded it to a normal web app in Azure. I can now use this web api successfully over the internet.

Now i read about the cost/gb of the bandwith in Azure and realized that if this web api is scaled and used alot this could end up being extremely expensive(more than i can afford). I read around some more and saw sites like Arvixe and more offering unlimited bandwith in shared hosts, however after digging some more i found out that as soon people start getting high bandwith theese sites ban you for exploiting the service. I read some more and see people saying you can use VPS and dedicated servers as a good choice. I look into this and see that you need some experience setting up theese which i dont have and that the cost of renting a computer with good cpu and ram costs alot aswell, all i'm really looking for is to host the site, no configurations is needed.

Now i've gotten to where i read about self hosting web api. I figured i could use my own computer which has alot better CPU and Ram than thoose i can afford as VPS etc. i see LOTS of examples. But i dont really understand how they can be used practically over the internet just with localhost.

**Questions:**

Would there be a good choice to host this web api myself and can i do it safely without to much knowledge?

Alot of people refer to iis which i have never used but seen alot of examples using localhost. Since i already own a url can i use this instead from iss to run this from my own computer? and would it be considered safe?

I also see alot of people using Owin self host which does not need iis. Would this be the better alternative? like this for example http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

**Conclusion:**

What it all comes down to is that i'm looking for a way for a beginner to host a web api over the internet without having to worry about bandwith and cpu usage getting to high for me as a private person to afford.

Any input or help about where i can begin with this very appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So firstly, I think you're confused by the term "self-host", this *usually* refers to a way of hosting an ASP.NET WebAPI application in a process **other than IIS**.  This does not refer (as I think you understand it to) to where to host the API from an internet access perspective.

> Would there be a good choice to host this web api myself and can i do it safely without to much knowledge?

No.  Don't do this, at best it will be difficult to configure and perform badly.  At worst it can actually expose your computer(s) @ home to some significant vulnerabilities.

> Alot of people refer to iis which i have never used but seen alot of examples using localhost. Since i already own a url can i use this instead from iss to run this from my own computer? and would it be considered safe?

IIS is Microsoft's web server and generally this is the host software that you would install to run an ASP.NET application (of any kind).  You *can* install this on Windows 7/8/10, but again I strongly recommend against this.

> I also see alot of people using Owin self host which does not need iis. Would this be the better alternative? like this for example http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

This goes to my first comment, you misunderstand what this means.

I wish I had some recommendations as to where you could host this at a very low cost, but I don't.  One thing I know you can do with Azure is to set up spending limits; you could use Azure to host the API but set a spending limit of say $100 and then when that limit is reached your API just becomes unavailable.  You haven't really specified what you want to use the API for, so I don't know if that would work for you or not, but it's a good way to at least test it out so you can get an idea what it's going to cost you more long term.

Comment: Okay thanks alot this helped me, i will not try to host it myself. Instead i'll try to find the best way to find a hosting service. The tip on putting a limit on Azure was great! I'll actually put that on $100 aswell since its the most i'd consider paying for it. I wish there was a service for high bandwith around this price, it feels like there's nothing in between, its either pay $3 or pay $1000.  I'll serve a social forum so i figured it could be used alot for people loading data from dabatase and making new posts etc. $100 gives you about 1.2TB of outbound data bandwith with Azure

Comment: I guess that can serve quite alot of api calls?

Comment: Yea, 1.2TB is a **lot** of bandwidth, especially if you can make sure you're able to accept and respond using [HTTP compression](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-web-api-compression).  Honestly with Azure I think you want to be more concerned with CPU/storage costs, I've never found the bandwidth costs to be significant myself.

Comment: Thanks for the link about compression, never heard of it before, I will look into that. Ye I'm currently running the db from another host since the db cost looked high on azure. Altough i store the images in azure blob storage. Dont know if this is a good strategi but.. ye